# Issue with installing dependencies in Angular Project

Tags: angular, dependencies, npm-install

I am trying to run an angular project in visual studio code, and when I try to install dependencies with npm install, I am getting this error:

[npm install errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVfyM.png)

I try running npm install --legacy-peer-deps, and then get more errors:

[npm install --legacy-peer-deps errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWPTp.png)

I'm being told to ignore the python errors, as they are low level errors that I don't need to worry about. I don't think python is required for the project anyways.

I have looked up this issue on this site and other websites, looking at suggestions on how I can fix the issue, and nothing seems to work. I've deleted the project and downloaded it again from the server, but that didn't fix it. I also uninstalled node.js, npm, and the angular cli from my machine and then reinstalled everything globally, thinking maybe it was a corrupted installation, but nothing changed either. I spent quite a bit of time last week with colleagues trying to resolve the issue and nothing we did was able to fix it. I thought maybe it was my machine, so I brought this project onto my personal computer to try and see if I could compile and run it, but I was getting similar errors on there as well.

Please let me know if there is more information that I should provide to help resolve this issue, and any suggestions as to how I can resolve this issue are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried to update the `@angular/cdk` package to version 14? If not, try to update it. Your project uses Angular 14 but has an outdated version of the Angular CDK. Maybe it was forgotten when updating.

Comment: I updated the @angular/cdk package, but nothing changed, I'm still getting the same errors.